# Prove $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)~dx=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

My attempt:

Cauchy's theorem gives $\int_0^R \sin(x^2)dx+\int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}\sin(z^2) dz+\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0\sin(z^2)dz=0$

Denote $\sin(x^2)=e^{-z^2}$

$R\to \infty$ implies $\int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}e^{-z^2} dz \to 0$.

Hence , $\int_0^R \sin(x^2)dx+\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0\sin(z^2)dz=0 \implies \int_0^R e^{-x^2}dx = -\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0e^{-z^2}dz$

My problem is solving $\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0e^{-z^2}dz$.

Any idea how to advance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Denote $\sin(z^2)=e^{-z^2}$

This is incorrect. They are NOT equal at all.

> $R\to \infty$ implies $\int_R^{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}e^{-z^2} dz \to 0$.

Why? You need to prove it.

> Hence , $\int_0^R \sin(x^2)dx+\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0\sin(z^2)dz=0 \implies \int_0^R e^{-x^2}dx = -\int_{Re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}^0e^{-z^2}dz$

You need to re-do everything.

Comment: I fixed that $sin(x^2)=e^{-z^2}$ , now is it correct ?

Comment: No, it should be $\sin z^2=\Im e^{i z^2}$